# React Material UI Tab custom css looks like a button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to make react material UI Tab look like a button that are different colors when they are active

Reference code : https://4ocqy.csb.app/

Comment: what is the problem itself ?

Comment: on active class have style are not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Tab` style from:

```js
style: {
  // tab style
  "&:active": {
     // select style
  }
}
```

To:

```js
style: {
  // tab style
  "&.Mui-selected": {
     // select style
  }
}
```

You can know the className of a selected `Tab` by inspecting it in the devtool:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66892344/react-material-ui-tab-custom-css-looks-like-a-button]